# Heatmap by palette using CUDA

Tags: cuda

I use CUDA to render (using raytracer) a scene onto screen and want to know what is the hottest spots on the screen: I measure the difference between values returned by `clock64` to know the run time for each pixel on the screen:

```
float start = clock64();
frame[y * w + x] = TraceRay(x, y, w, h);
counters[y * w + x] = clock64() - start;`
```

Currently I do the following to get something like a heatmap:

```
auto p = thrust::cuda::par.on(stream);
thrust::device_ptr< const float > c = thrust::device_pointer_cast(counters);
auto m = thrust::minmax_element(p, c, c + w * h);
thrust::device_ptr< Color > f = thrust::device_pointer_cast(frame);
#ifndef __CUDACC_EXTENDED_LAMBDA__
#error "nvcc --expt-extended-lambda"
#endif
auto l = [=] __device__ (float c) -> Color
{
    auto color = (c - *m.first) / float(*m.second - *m.first);
    return {color, 0.0f, 1.0f - color, 1.0f};
};
thrust::transform(p, c, c + w * h, f, l);
```

But distribution of the values resulted is too wide and most of them are blue and some small subset of most interesting pixels became almost red (hottest spots, hardest to calculate). There is almost no valuable gradient.

Also I want to define a heatmap by palette with defining a colors in reference points (percentiles for the `counters` values). Like it can be done in `gnuplot`:

[image: desired heatmap]

I think I could *rank* all the values in `counters` and apply a palette to them:

- First of all, I need to sort all the values from `counters` previously extended them by (empty) `color` field and by coordinates (`x`, `y`) (or simply by index in the source linear array). Only value from `counters` should participate into comparator of the sorting.
- After that palette should be applied. It is simple assign to the `color` field of the value of piecewise linear interpolation of colors given from the palette mapped onto the `[0;1]` interval and then mapped onto linear index of the sorted array.
- After all I can draw all the `color`s using `x` and `y` coordinates (or sort them back by linear index field).

Is there a place for CUDA in implementation of the algorithm? As I know there is radix sort, but is it applicable to the structures with `key` not span the whole structure?

Comment: "too broad"?! I ask an implementation of concrete algorithm. Maybe today I can answer by myself. But I wanted to get intuitions from the community.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is not perfect (on of the sorts can be completely avoided in favour of permutation; memory can be reused instead of reallocated every next frame; palette can be maden extendable), but quite workable. It draws in shades of red only upper 5% of most heavy blocks. All the others are drawn in the shades of gren to blue.

```
__global__
void drawHeatmap(unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const Color * heatmap, cudaSurfaceObject_t frame)
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if ((x >= w) || (y >= h)) {
        return;
    }
    surf2Dwrite< Color >(heatmap[w * y + x], frame, sizeof(Color) * x, y);
}

void CudaRaytracer::buildHeatmap(cudaStream_t stream,
                                 unsigned int w, unsigned int h,
                                 float * counters,
                                 cudaSurfaceObject_t frame)
{
    assert(counters);
    auto p = thrust::cuda::par.on(stream);
    thrust::device_ptr< float > c = thrust::device_pointer_cast(counters);
    const auto size = w * h;
    thrust::device_vector< unsigned int > indices(size);
    thrust::sequence(p, indices.begin(), indices.end());
    thrust::sort_by_key(p, c, c + size, indices.begin());
#ifndef __CUDACC_EXTENDED_LAMBDA__
#error "nvcc --expt-extended-lambda"
#endif
    auto make_palette = [=] __device__ (unsigned int index) -> Color
    {
        constexpr unsigned int palette_size = 3;
        static const float reference_points[palette_size] = {0.0f, 0.95f, 1.0f};
        float pos = index / float(size);
        unsigned int i = 0;
        for (; i < palette_size; ++i) {
            if (pos < reference_points[i]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        __syncwarp();
        static const Color palette[palette_size] = {{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
        float weight = (pos - reference_points[i - 1]) / (reference_points[i] - reference_points[i - 1]);
        return weight * (palette[i - 1] - palette[i]) + palette[i];
    };
    thrust::device_vector< Color > heatmap(size);
    auto index = thrust::make_counting_iterator(0u);
    thrust::transform(p, index, index + size, heatmap.begin(), make_palette);
    thrust::sort_by_key(p, indices.begin(), indices.end(), heatmap.begin());
    auto gridSize = deriveGridSize(w, h);
    drawHeatmap<<< gridSize, blockSize, 0, stream >>>(w, h, heatmap.data().get(), frame);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
}
```

On GeForce RTX 2060 it gives about 30ms to render.